# how to configure jsdom for headless backbone.router testing

Tags: backbone.js, mocha.js, sinon, jsdom

Im tring to get a headless  backbone.router  test to work with jsdom but having a bit of a problem solving this cryptic error:

```
  Route
    MinRouter
      1) "before each" hook

  0 passing (167ms)
  1 failing

  1) Route "before each" hook:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
      at _.extend.start (/home/user/min/vendor/backbone.js:1398:68)
      at /home/user/min/__test__/uroute/testrouter.js:14:30
      at Object.jsdom.env.done (/home/user/min/__test__/helpers/clientenv.js:30:13)
      at /home/user/min/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:249:18
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

and here is how is setup  jsdom env:

```
jsdom.env({
    html: html,
    done: function(errs, window) {
        global.window = window;
        ...
        global.BP.Router = {};
        global.navigator = {  browser: 'foo'   };
        callback();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out this is required in jsdom

```
jsdom.env({
    html: html,
    done: function(errs, window) {
        global.window = window;
        ...
        global.BP.Router = {};
        global.navigator = {  userAgent: 'node-js' };
        callback();
    }
});
```